# text based adventure game JavaScript simplified way?

Tags: javascript, text, adventure

I am currently working on a text adventure game for as a small project and was wondering if there is a simple method other than what I am doing now.

```
//Pro-log of the game 
if (Start == false)
{
    if (input.indexOf("y") > -1) {
        if (input == "y") {
            $("<p>request granted... video uplink enabled...</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(3000);
            $("<p>audio only... no video attached to distress signal...</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(5000);
            $("<p>'If you... are listening to.... this go back!..' </p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(7000);
            $("<p>end of audio... request to doc ship[y/n]...</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(9000);
            Start = true;
            DocShip = true;

        }
        $("#console").scrollTop($("#console")[0].scrollHeight);
        $("#command_line").val("");


    }
    if (input.indexOf("n") > -1) {
        if (input == "n") {
            $("<p>mark company policy is to attend and aid all destress signals....[y]...</p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(3000);


        }
        $("#console").scrollTop($("#console")[0].scrollHeight);
        $("#command_line").val("");


    }
}
else if (DocShip == true)
{
    if (input.indexOf("y") > -1) {
            if (input == "y") {
                $("<p>request granted... ten minutes till destination... </p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(3000);
                }
            $("#console").scrollTop($("#console")[0].scrollHeight);
            $("#command_line").val("");
            }
        if (input.indexOf("n") > -1) {
            if (input == "n") {
                $("<p>mark company policy is to attend and aid all destress signals...[y]...  </p>").insertBefore("#placeholder").hide().fadeIn(3000);


            }
            $("#console").scrollTop($("#console")[0].scrollHeight);
            $("#command_line").val("");


        }
}
```

So currently I am using variables by having them true or false to move through scenes but am aware this will get very messy very fast. Is there a simpler way to have it so when the player enters an answer it checks it then moves to the correct bit of text without having to move to another if statement. Any help to clean this up would be appreciated. I have an idea of what I am doing and I can keep doing this to work through the game but was hoping someone would have a better solution.

Comment: That's JavaScript, not Java, right?

Comment: looks like javascript + jquery

Comment: Why do you use both `input.indexOf("y")` and `input == "y"`?

Comment: Well, I have no idea, but I'm just going to throw this at you: *state machine*, maybe?

Comment: Yeah it is sorry thats my mistake Im using JavaScript and Jquery its meant to be a web based adventure game. I've already made one like this but it is very tedious was hoping someone could have some input and show me a better solution.

Comment: Thousands of `if/then` statements is not the way to implement something like this. You should have data structures that represent all the different rooms, with links to other rooms.

Comment: would you be able to show me a simple break down of the structure it should be set out in and how to link to other rooms please? Im not asking for you to do everything just a simple layout that I can see.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what he was talking about, but you might be able to make something like this https://jsfiddle.net/56g7w76z/ (type the number next to where you want to go)  you could add to it by including an array of strings you want to fade in once they reach certain locations before they can choose to move again.

Comment: thats cool thank you, Ill see if I can get it to work with the dialog as well